# Oracle 12c Installation failed to access the temporary location

Tags: windows, oracle

I have Windows 8.1 64-bit OS running on 64-bit architecture. I am installing a fresh copy of Oracle 12C, means I haven't installed any version before on my system.

During the installation, I encountered the following error message;

```
Cause - Failed to access the temporary location.  Action - Ensure that the current user has required permissions to access the temporary location.  Additional Information:
 - Framework setup check failed on all the nodes  - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available  - Action: User Action Not Available Summary of the failed nodes al-naseeha  - Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "al-naseeha"  - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available  - Action: User Action Not Available
```

The error code is [INS-30131]. I've the full privileges of an administrator-ship. I also tried to resolve this problem via the following command;

```
net use \\localhost\c$
```

But in no vain. Can you please help me sort out this issue.

Comment: Refer to this thread, you might be able to fix your issue https://community.oracle.com/thread/2567145

Comment: Try killing `RemoteExecService.exe` if it's running. Did the trick for me.

Comment: Apparently this question is too old to migrate, but surely it would have been a better fit for [su] or [sf].

Answer (score 29):

The error is caused due to administrative shares are being disabled. If they cannot be enabled then perform the following workaround:

> ### 6.2.23 INS-30131 Error When Installing Oracle Database or Oracle Client
>
> If the administrative shares are not enabled when performing a single
>   instance Oracle Database or Oracle Client installation for 12c Release
>   1 (12.1) on Microsoft Windows 7, Microsoft Windows 8, and Microsoft
>   Windows 10, then the installation fails with an `INS-30131` error.
>
> #### Workaround:
>
> Execute the `net share` command to ensure that the administrative
>   shares are enabled. If they are disabled, then enable them by
>   following the instructions in the Microsoft Windows documentation.
>   Alternatively, perform the client or server installation by specifying
>   the following options:
>
> - For a client installation:
>
>   `-ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"`
> - For a server installation:
>
>   `-ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"`
>
> This issue is tracked with Oracle bug 21452473.

Source: [Oracle Database Release Notes (Section 6.2.23)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBN/toc.htm#CJAGBJDB)

Comment: I had the same problem with asker. As far as I'm concerned, I have no issues with administrative share; I have no OracleRemExecService process running; I have no special characters in my username; and I have set custom temp folders that doesn't contain space to all users in my computer. I need to install only the database client. And somehow... this answer works for me: `setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"` Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Looking at Oracle's support site, it could be one of two things (may be #2 in your case, but including both).

Problem 1:

1. Enable administrative share for C$ (Please check with your System Admin to do this or See Microsoft document http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984)
2. Check that it is ok:

   - net use \\c$ should work
   - the current user (i.e. user in administrator group) should have all privileges on the default share
3. Retry the installation
4. Remove the administrative share again

Problem 2: 
Remove the OracleRemExecService before doing the Oracle Client 12c Release 1 32-bit or 64-bit installation on
the same Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) after installing the Oracle 64-bit or 32-bit software .

- Go to the Windows 'Services'
- Stop OracleRemExecServiceV2

( This service is having a intelligence .Once someone tries to stop it this service gets deleted. 
This is due to the fact ,that this service is not running from the Oracle Home like other oracle services ,but from temp . 
For example : *C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\oraremservi...* 
)

- Then try to install the Oracle 12c 32-bit or 64-bit on the same Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks, stopping the OracleRemServiceV2 solved it for me. Can you explain why we had to do this? After the installation it looks like the service started back up again, this is good?

Comment: For some reason when I tried to stop the service it was saying that it could not be found as an installed service, even through it was showing up in the Services list.  I removed the service from the registry, and this fixed the problem for me as well.

Comment: Down voted because, the answer gives only technical points on what to do, but not how to do? Some of us are not experts.

Answer (score 9):

I found another situation in which this problem may arise (despite following the steps listed by other users above) and that's when the username of the user you're logged in as has an '_' on it. The path it will try to use to find the temp directory is whatever is set in %TEMP%. I managed to work around it by:

1. Launch cmd.exe in Administrator mode
2. SET TEMP = C:\TEMP
3. Run the installer from that command window

Installed successfully that way.

Answer (score 5):

This error could caused by a username with Chinese characters.

1. Create a new local windows user with an English username.  Make sure there are no spaces in the username.
2. Install Oracle using the user you just created.

Answer (score 5):

(Solution) Same problem: Windows 10 vs. Oracle 11g (11.2.0.4)

The problem arises again with the final release of Windows 10 (and Server 2016 Preview 3 too) using e. g. Oracle 11g (11.2.0.4, 64 bit) after installation tasks worked fine with several preview builds of Windows 10. All things said above are o. k. resp. do not work.

The ultimate cause is an incompatibility of OracleRemExecService (vs. RemoteExecService.exe): as known, at the beginning of installation process it is created via %TEMP%\oraremservice. If you watch it e. g. with Sysinternals' ProcessMonitor using an appropriate filter, you can see several crashes (the most of them with "buffer Overflow") and restarts, and there are also corresponding with messages in Windows' "System" event log.

If you start (after deleting the HKLM\Software\oracle in the registry) the installation several times (more than three times - see below) it suddenly works.
The reason for this behaviour is Windows' "Fault Tolerant Heap" mechanism (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd744764(v=vs.85).aspx) that creates after three attempts within 60 minutes (see http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/10/02/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-fault-tolerant-heap-and-memory-management.aspx) a FTH entry in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\FTH\State and a corresponding shim in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers.
Although the content of the FTH entry is related to the current process of RemoteExecService.exe you can import the registry keys to a system before you start the DB installation. If you set Windows' %TEMP% environment variable **and also** %TMP% (due to the fact that Oracle uses **both** directories while creating the things around OracleRemExecService) to a predefined value (e. g. C:\TEMP) you are able to use this for all your installation tasks as follows (unfortunately, it works only with Windows 10, not Server 2016 - updated 2015-09-24, see below):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Temp\\oraremservice\\RemoteExecService.exe"="FaultTolerantHeap"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\FTH\State]
"C:\\Temp\\oraremservice\\RemoteExecService.exe"=hex:10,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,\
  0c,b4,ff,0c,52,00,65,00,6d,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,45,00,78,00,65,00,63,00,53,\
  00,65,00,72,00,76,00,69,00,63,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Update 2015-09-24: 
With Server 2016 (Preview 3), it's a little bit more tricky: first you also have to set the environment variable %TEMP% e. g. to C:\Temp and to import the registry keys above (after this, it's no bad idea to restart the system).
Than you start the Oracle installation using an additional parameter:

setup.exe -debug

If you watch what happens in %TEMP% you can see that the folder %TEMP%\oraremservice\ is created twice: after first creation, the installer seems to notice that the service does not work, deletes the folder and creates it again. After this, the Installation process works as expected.

Update 2015-11-27: 
- Using Windows Server 2016 Preview 4, the workaround via "setup.exe -debug" is not necessary anymore; you can proceed as described for Windows 10.
- Of course, you do not need the procedure with new C:\TEMP vs. %TEMP% and %TMP% if you have a defined user (e. g. Administrator). Then you can use modified registry items like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\oraremservice\\RemoteExecService.exe"="FaultTolerantHeap"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\FTH\State]
"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\oraremservice\\RemoteExecService.exe"=hex:10,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,\
  0c,b4,ff,0c,52,00,65,00,6d,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,45,00,78,00,65,00,63,00,53,\
  00,65,00,72,00,76,00,69,00,63,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Update 2017-01-31: Tested all builds of Windows 10 (Insider Preview) until now, so we have seen a new problem coming up with build 15002: the Oracle setup isn't able to determine the PATH variable anymore (the variable itself, not a wrong content or so on!). So all attempts to install the Oracle DB fail. Comparing the registry of the Windows versions and "playing around" with this variable and their contents did not help. The only work-around is to edit the related XML file \64bit|32bit\stage\cvu\cvu_prereq.xml and delete in the section  all tags  ...  (or this tag only in the last item "Windows Server 2012"). And btw: despite of we are primary using Oracle 11g this new  installation problem also occurs using the up to date setup of Oracle 12c...

Comment: Welcome to SO! While your answer looks fine, it is quite hard to read. Please add some formatting (e.g. put the reg file into code tags) and improve the readability of your wall of text. Then it should attract some upvotes :-)

Answer (score 4):

Try cleaning your hosts file.

I spent about half a day on this, and none of these answers worked for me.  I finally found the solution hinted at on OTN (the last place I look when I run into Oracle issues), and someone mentioned looking at the hosts file.  I had recently modified the hosts file because this particular machine didn't have access to DNS.

I had a line for this host:

```
123.123.123.123     fully.qualified.domain.name.com     hostname
```

Commenting out the line above allowed me to install the Oracle client.

Comment: This worked for me too - using the 11.2.0.4 installer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The main problem in your case would be failure of accessing **\\localhost\c$**

If you get an error while trying to access the Windows hidden C share (C$):

> C:\> net use \\localhost\c$
>   
>   System error 53 has occurred.
>   
>   The network path was not found.

You may find the following articles useful: [KB254210](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254210) and [KB951016](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016).

A simple thing is just to make sure your TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper and Server services are running (Start-Run, services.msc) and try again:

> C:\> net use \localhost\c$
>   
>   The command completed successfully.

Of course, your user must be either an administrator or be part of the administrator group.

If it still fails, manually edit the registry (Start-Run, regedit). Browse to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

and create a new DWORD value LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy set to 1


After solving this issue and installing Oracle Database Server, you can disable back your **TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper** service if you don't need it anymore.


References: http://groglogs.blogspot.ro/2013/11/windows-cannot-access-hidden-c-admin.html




**For others:**

If you don't have the problem with **\\localhost\c$**, then you might have the other problem with your username as the others stated (e.g. username with '_' in it):

This will get solved by changing **TEMP** and **TMP** environment variables from a command line and then running **setup.exe** from there.

**If this still doesn't work:**

Try running setup.exe with "**-debug**" option and see what happens in there.

You may also want to check what's in the .log files created in your %TEMP% folder (e.g. ssproiut_%number%.log)

Answer (score 3):

You can configure setup.exe to skip this check using the parameters below -

```
setup.exe -ignorePrereq -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Summarized: Oracle under Windows has problems with usernames containing non-English letters or special characters:**

If your machine is fresh installed, first look here. All the network related or 32 vs. 64 related issues may be not significant for you:

As others already pointed out partly, this error is highly related to the name of the TEMP dir.
It occurred to me when installing Oracle 11g first time on a totally fresh Windows (e.g. Server 2008 R2 or Win 7, not important).

As I found out, on my machine the problem was, that the username contained a German special character ("ö"). Moreover Oracle cannot handle any special character, I assume, the TEMP path is limited to letters. Other colleagues here have reported problems with underscore and chinese characters.

Explanation:
In Windows the TEMP dir (environment variable %TEMP%) is by default in the user directory, for example:

```
C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Temp
```

If "ThisUser" contains special or non-ASCII characters, then  in this case this affects the TEMP path, and that is where Oracle is gettings problems.

Setting the TEMP dir to different directory is of course another possibility instead of installing with another username.

Moreover, Oracle is not a fully native Windows citizen which everybody will recognize, if he opens the Oracle install logfile with notepad ;-)
Obviously, this is not programmed cleanly and portable, e.g. with using "std::endl" instead of "\n" .
(Yes, Notepad++ and other editors do the job.)

Overall, my impression is, if the database were of the same quality as it's installer, Oracle would not be so successful ..

Last remark: Yes, after failed install because of the special characters you see only one Oracle service named OracleRemExecService, but there is no reason to stop this manually as recommended in other solutions, if you are able to install again a fresh OS..

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I had the Server service stopped and this gave exactly this same issue.
So started the Server service and the installation worked.

Answer (score 1):

This problem arises due to the administrative share.

Here is the solution :

1. Set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System DWORD` value: `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` to 1
2. Go to this link: http://www.snehashish.com/install-oracle-database-12c-software/ Follow **8th point**.
   *It helped me a lot.*
   After creating the hidden share (c$) it should look like this (you can ignore the description tab)

[image]
And for remaining you can follow the above link.

And let me know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

If your user account has spaces in it and you have tried all the above but none worked,

> I recommended you create a new windows user account and give it an
>   administrative privilege, not standard.

Log out of your old account and log into this new account and try installing again. It worked well.

Comment: Fixing this worked for me. My system name had a dash in it.

Answer (score 1):

Install it from CMD using the command

```
setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"
```

[Reference](https://orawiki.org/2016/10/11/initial-setup-required-for-the-execution-of-installer-validation-failed/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when attempting to install 12c 32x client on Windows 10.  `"net use \\localhost\c$"` worked, but when I substituted "localhost" the computer's "name" (e.g., `\\my-computer\c$`), I got the "`System error 53 ...`".  Oracle seems to prefer the computer's name.

What fixed it: we temporarily disabled the IPv6 protocol for the computer (our network uses IPv4).  How to do this: Control Panel --> Network and Sharing Center --> Change adapter settings --> right click on Ethernet Connection --> Properties --> uncheck "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6) --> OK.  That should disable it.  After that, `\\my-computer\c$` ran successfully in the command prompt.  Then the Oracle installer finally completed and we were able to tnsping the database server.

Just to test it out, we re-enabled IPv6 and restarted the computer.  `\\my-computer\c$` failed in the cmd prompt, but tnsping still functioned correctly.

I hope this helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Please ensure that your admin user name does not contain any " " space or different characters except the Latin alphabet.
if there is a problem you have to create a new user account with administrator privileges and you can perform an installation with that user.