# Unable to start Oracle client 32bit on windows

Tags: oracle

I am facing an issue while installing oracle client.

- Currently,There are no Oracle services running. When i start installing Oracle Client it abruptly closes, and when i check the services.msc I can see "oracleremexecservice" running, which does not have option to stop (tried to even force stop the service, did not work).
- So i deleted the service from the registry and rebooted the system."oracleremexecservice" vanished.
- Once again I start to install the Oracle client, installation fails and "Oracleremexecservice" gets created again and is running.

  Can anybody help me to solve this? I deleted oracleremexecservice from registry and temp folder, Am i missing anything? I need to delete this oracleremexecservice permanently from my system in order to complete the installation.
  Below is the screenshot of the service:

[image]

Comment: what are you installing the client for, exactly? In other words, how are you intending to use it?

Comment: also this looks vaguely familiar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546892/oracle-12c-installation-failed-to-access-the-temporary-location