# Oracle 19c :: Failed to set ACL's for specified User

Tags: oracle, installation, acl, net-use, oracle19c

I'm trying to install a fresh new downloaded Oracle Database 19c on my Windows 10 Home and I receive the error: `Failed to set ACL's for specified User.`

[image]

In the logs details I see mentioned updating registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_OraDB19Home1` I don't see nothing unusual there.

I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546892/oracle-12c-installation-failed-to-access-the-temporary-location/38106173) and I:

- run `net share`
- run `net use \\localhost\c$`
- I `Stop` and `Disabled` and the service **OracleRemExecServiceV2**
- I also run with PowerShell as Administrator the command `setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"`
- Of course I have also created a brand new user for Oracle with a brand new password. And I also tried the Windows user within the Administrator group
- I went to regedit and on **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System** I created a new `DWORD` value `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` set to `1`
- I disabled **Windows Defender** and the whole **Firewall**
- Then I tried the **Debug mode** so run from an elevated prompt I run `setup.exe -debug -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"` and as result I got:

[image]

```
native operation failed with WSE-000053: Windows application programming interface (API) SetFileSecurityW failed.
```

and

```
O/S-Error: (OS 123) The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

which makes absolutely no sense to me because it looks like a Windows error.

How it can be so hard to install Oracle DB on a brand new machine with tons of CPU and RAM?

What ACL means and how to [set it up](https://ss64.com/ps/set-acl.html)?

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what makes your life miserable:

> Oracle Database 19c on my Windows 10 **Home**

Oracle isn't/wasn't/won't (as far as I can tell) be supported on any MS Windows **Home** edition. True, some people made it work, but that's more matter of *luck*. You should upgrade operating system.

Or, maybe a better option, download one of [Pre-Built Developer VMs (for Oracle VM VirtualBox)](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Installation guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/operating-system-checklist-oracle-database-installation-microsoft-windows.html)

says

> Oracle Database for Windows x64 is supported on the following
>   operating system versions: Windows 10 x64 - Pro, Enterprise, and
>   Education editions

Oracle 19c is not supported on Windows 10 Home edition.

If you really want to have Oracle 19c on Windows, try to create a virtual machine with a supported Windows Server evaluation version. Or try to install Oracle 18 XE.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was installing Oracle 19c in Windows server 2019. I had previously installed weblogic in d:\Oracle\Middleware and I wanted to install oracle client in d:\Oracle\product\19.3.0\Client_1 but the ACL error was there. To fix it I had to choose d:\app\oracle (a new directory) to do the client installation.

Answer (score 0):

After many days, switching firewalls off and on, changing rights of Admin and so on.. I could not install OEE setup in D:\Oracle .. Once I tried D:\Test\Oracle it worked successfully. Why, Oracle, Why!

I'm thinking about deleting and clearing up all Oracle stuff on the machine (or start a fresh new environment and start again).

If anything helps to any reader (I searched the whole internet), please try the following:

- try another path on same drive
- try disabling firewall / antivirus if that blocks the proces
- make sure u are the owner of the map
- or make sure have Full Admin rights